# SQL Server- using a PIVOT function

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, ssms

I need help figuring out how to add a `PIVOT` function into this SQL query for this question.

Find the percentage of claims that are processed per state(status), within their SLA, per month, for the last 12 months.

Here is what I have so far...

```
SELECT cs.ERRetroResponseStatusId
    , DATENAME(MONTH, c.CreatedDate) [Month]
    , SUM(CASE
            WHEN ERRetroResponseStatusId = 1 and (DATEDIFF(HOUR, c.CreatedDate, GETDATE()))<24 THEN 1 
        WHEN ERRetroResponseStatusId = 3 and (DATEDIFF(DAY, c.CreatedDate, GETDATE()))<45 THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 END) AS CountOfGroupedStatusIDs
    , COUNT(cs.ERRetroResponseStatusId) AS TotalAmountOfClaimsInStatus
    , ROUND(100.00 * COUNT(cs.ERRetroResponseStatusId) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(),2) AS [Percentage]
--convert(decimal(18,2),x) 
FROM ERRetroClaimResponse cs
    INNER JOIN ERRetroState s ON cs.ERRetroResponseStatusId = s.Id
    LEFT JOIN ERRetroClaim c ON c.Id = cs.ERRetroClaimId
WHERE cs.CreatedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
and cs.ERRetroResponseStatusId in (1,3)
GROUP BY cs.ERRetroResponseStatusId, DATENAME(MONTH, c.CreatedDate)
```

```
Id   ** ClaimID ** StatusID **      CreatedDate        ** CreatedBy
===========================================================================
1174 **   977   **    1     ** 2018-06-01 18:01:31.387 **     1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1175 **   978   **    1     ** 2018-06-01 18:01:31.387 **     1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1176 **   979   **    1     ** 2018-06-01 18:01:31.387 **     1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1177 **   980   **    1     ** 2018-06-01 18:01:31.403 **     1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1178 **   981   **    1     ** 2018-06-01 18:01:31.403 **     1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Could you add the query you have at the moment to the question.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: I am using SSMS

Comment: @snoosan So add `SQL Server` tag to your question.

Comment: Why do you want to use a `pivot` here? Can you provide your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

This query will pivot your status ids into column names, with months listed as row values.

```
;WITH AggData AS
(
    SELECT cs.ERRetroResponseStatusId
        , DATENAME(MONTH, c.CreatedDate) AS [Month]
        , SUM(CASE
                WHEN ERRetroResponseStatusId = 1 and (DATEDIFF(HOUR, c.CreatedDate, GETDATE()))<24 THEN 1 
            WHEN ERRetroResponseStatusId = 3 and (DATEDIFF(DAY, c.CreatedDate, GETDATE()))<45 THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 END) AS CountOfGroupedStatusIDs
        , COUNT(cs.ERRetroResponseStatusId) AS TotalAmountOfClaimsInStatus
    FROM ERRetroClaimResponse cs
    INNER JOIN ERRetroState s ON cs.ERRetroResponseStatusId = s.Id
    LEFT JOIN ERRetroClaim c ON c.Id = cs.ERRetroClaimId
    WHERE cs.CreatedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
        AND cs.ERRetroResponseStatusId in (1,3)
    GROUP BY cs.ERRetroResponseStatusId, DATENAME(MONTH, c.CreatedDate)
)
SELECT 
    [Month]
    , [1] AS 'For ERRetroResponseStatusId = 1'
    , [3] AS 'For ERRetroResponseStatusId = 3'
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ERRetroResponseStatusId
        ,[Month]
        , ROUND((CountOfGroupedStatusIDs / TotalAmountOfClaimsInStatus) * 100.00, 2) AS [Percentage]
    FROM AggData
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Percentage])
    FOR ERRetroResponseStatusId IN ([1],[3])
) AS PivotTable
```

And this query will pivot the months into column names.

```
;WITH AggData AS
(
    SELECT cs.ERRetroResponseStatusId
        , DATENAME(MONTH, c.CreatedDate) AS [Month]
        , SUM(CASE
                WHEN ERRetroResponseStatusId = 1 and (DATEDIFF(HOUR, c.CreatedDate, GETDATE()))<24 THEN 1 
            WHEN ERRetroResponseStatusId = 3 and (DATEDIFF(DAY, c.CreatedDate, GETDATE()))<45 THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 END) AS CountOfGroupedStatusIDs
        , COUNT(cs.ERRetroResponseStatusId) AS TotalAmountOfClaimsInStatus
    FROM ERRetroClaimResponse cs
    INNER JOIN ERRetroState s ON cs.ERRetroResponseStatusId = s.Id
    LEFT JOIN ERRetroClaim c ON c.Id = cs.ERRetroClaimId
    WHERE cs.CreatedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
        AND cs.ERRetroResponseStatusId in (1,3)
    GROUP BY cs.ERRetroResponseStatusId, DATENAME(MONTH, c.CreatedDate)
)
SELECT 
    ERRetroResponseStatusId
    ,[January]
    ,[February]
    ,[March]
    ,[April]
    ,[May]
    ,[June]
    ,[July]
    ,[August]
    ,[September]
    ,[October]
    ,[November]
    ,[December]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ERRetroResponseStatusId
        ,[Month]
        , ROUND((CountOfGroupedStatusIDs / TotalAmountOfClaimsInStatus) * 100.00, 2) AS [Percentage]
    FROM AggData
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Percentage])
    FOR [Month] IN ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],[December])
) AS PivotTable
```